# jQuery not working on homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is really weird.  If i go to my site www.example.com the jQuery will not work on my index file/homepage.  However, if I type in www.example.com/index.html the jQuery loads up just fine.  Any ideas what is going on or how to fix this?

http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com

http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com/index.html

Comment: You own the `www.example.com`? Awesome! No jQuery code there! Neither we know how your homepage gets the script! :P

Comment: When you click view source on either page, is there a distinction?

Comment: Do you have another file named `index`, like `index.php` that may not have your updated code?

Comment: Yeah, as @smartcaveman and Glenn says there might be two files?

Comment: @SperanskyDanil  http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com

http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com/index.html

Comment: @smartcaveman I checked and there are not two files, I posted links to the real website below, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use jQuery before you've included it:

```
  <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.register").fancybox({
        'type': 'iframe'
    });
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
```

Ensure that this is first:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will keep in mind that it needs to go first or will not load properly.  I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com/

Some tag is not present, eg : `<body>` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Japanese Language Friend - An Artistic Approach to Learning Japanese! </title>
  <META name="description" content="Learn Japanese by stimulating artwork! Join our community and lay down the first stepping stone to improving your Japanese language skills"><META name="keywords" content="Japanese art, Japanese, Japan, Learning Japanese, learning japanese, study japanese, fluent japanese,  japanese language friend, help with japanese, amazon japanese language, second language, japanese language community, japanese language friends, japanese language friend">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://japanesefriend.zxq.net" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 07 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```